# Не могу ввести данные в БД полученные из raw_input()

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

Каким образом я могу ввести данные в БД через `raw_input()`?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('one.sqlite')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test(Name TEXT, login TEXT, pass TEXT)")

with con:
    a = raw_input('Ввести значение: ')
    b = raw_input('Ввести значение: ')
    c = raw_input('Пароль: ')

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(a, b, c)")

con.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю насчет python 2.7 в python 3 это:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys

con = lite.connect('one.sqlite')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE test(Name TEXT, login TEXT, pass TEXT)")

with con:
    a = raw_input('Ввести зеначение: ')
    b = raw_input('Ввести значение: ')
    c = raw_input('Пароль: ')

    cur.execute("INSERT INTO test VALUES(?, ?, ?)", [a, b, c])

con.close()
```